# Selecting a .OFT based on answer to ComboBox

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have created a combobox with 3 options. I have 3 types of .OFT that correlate with this combobox. The combobox is named `Study_String`.

```
Dim Study_Stage As String

If Study_Stage <> "Start-Up" Or Study_Stage <> "Closed at IRB" Then

    Set objMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("X:\Users\Test Realm\OFT Template Maintenance.oft")

End If

If Study_Stage = "Maintenance" Or Study_Stage <> "Closed at IRB" Then

    Set objMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("X:\Users\Test Realm\OFT Template Start Up.oft")

End If

If Study_Stage <> "Maintenance" Or Study_Stage <> "Start-Up" Then

    Set objMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("X:\Users\Test Realm\OFT Template Closure.oft")

End If
```

As it stands right now, it just uses the 'OFT TEMPLATE CLOSURE.OFT' and won't use the other two.

Comment: And where are you assigning `Study_Stage` with the value of the `Study_String` combobox? Have you tried debugging your code to inspect whether the value of `Study_Stage` matches what you expect?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Study_Stage is the name of the combobox, so the option they select is the value.

Comment: But your code doesn't say that. It declares `Study_Stage As String`. See, `StudyStageBox.Value` would have been much more explicit - especially given how you expressly mention that the combobox is named `Study_String`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want ElseIf.
Have a look at this

```
If Study_Stage <> "Start-Up" Or Study_Stage <> "Closed at IRB" Then
    Set objMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("X:\Users\Test Realm\OFT Template Maintenance.oft")
ElseIf Study_Stage = "Maintenance" Or Study_Stage <> "Closed at IRB" Then
    Set objMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("X:\Users\Test Realm\OFT Template Start Up.oft")
ElseIf Study_Stage <> "Maintenance" Or Study_Stage <> "Start-Up" Then
    Set objMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("X:\Users\Test Realm\OFT Template Closure.oft")
End If
```

In your code, every if block will execute. Then one that runs last wins.
Also - 
Your conditions make little sense. I don't know the logic behind this, but when you see `... <> ... Or ... <> ...` there is often a logic error.

Comment: @OP: now might be a good opportunity to read up about breakpoints (F9) and step-through (F8) debugger tools. Upvoted.

Comment: I can't get 'Study_Stage =' to work, so I'm having to do it this way. I'll look up the F9 and F8 things you suggested Mathieu. Thank you!

Comment: I'm quite sure you are wrong. The condition `Study_Stage <> "Start-Up" Or Study_Stage <> "Closed at IRB"` will always return True. The same goes for `Study_Stage <> "Maintenance" Or Study_Stage <> "Start-Up"`

Comment: If s_N0 = "Closed at IRB" Then

Set objMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("X:\...\OFT Template Closure.oft")

ElseIf s_N0 = "Maintenance" Then

Set objMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("X:\...\OFT Template.oft")

ElseIf s_N0 = "Start-Up" Then

Set objMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("X:\...\OFT Template Start Up.oft")

End If

I got it to work using 'If/ElseIf' and using '=' instead of '<>' and changing the combobox name from 'Study_Stage' to 's_N0'

Works as intended now; I just can't get right click to work on my UserForm now, but I can't figure out how to fix that one.